# How to quit finder

Tags: terminal, finder, dock, ios

I am trying to quit finder along with the dock and status bar through terminal and I can't seem to find out how

Answer (score 10):

In Terminal use `killall Finder` will kill the Finder process, which will then automatically relaunch as a fresh new Finder process.

If you restore finder frequently crate a menu item to Quit it.

```
defaults write com.apple.finder QuitMenuItem -bool YES
```

Choosing this will actually quit the Finder as if it was an application, and it will not relaunch automatically in this case. But you will have to Restart. It has to be running all the time since it is the program that runs the graphical interface you interact with. If you force quit it, the Operating System will restart it automatically.

Comment: is there a way to quit it in terminal or through a .command file where it doesn't relaunch?

Comment: @scribbleNerd Please edit your question directly to add these details. While doing so please also indicate what you want to run instead of Finder in this case.

Comment: Just to note: You will lose all your desktop items if you kill it and force it to not relaunch. Unless that is the desired outcome, ofc.

Comment: @ScribbleNerd not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but the Finder is an essential integrated tool of OSX.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to quit Finder:

## Force quit window

Open the force quit window using command-option-escape, then choose Finder-relaunch.  The only problem is that it will reopen.

## Activity monitor

Open activity monitor, then choose Finder and day to end process.  I haven't tried this, but it should work.

Comment: the activity monitor meothod works but is there a way to do this through terminal or a .command file?

Comment: Try https://smallbusiness.chron.com/kill-application-mac-terminal-32823.html.  If it works, I will add it to my answer.

Comment: nope that reopens it

Comment: You kan kill it using maestro I've found.